# How to get info from a string with repeating pattern?

Tags: java, regex, string

Hello I wanna get information from a string with repeating pattern in it.
For example:

> Matematika 1#1#0@Fizika 1#1#6@Osnovi na injenernoto proektirane 1#1#5@PIK 1#1#6@Matematika 2#2#6@Fizika 2#2#6@Osnovi na injenernoto proektirane 2#2#4@

I tried with:

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(.+)[@]+");
    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("((.+)[#]+(\\d)[#]+(\\d)[@])+");
    Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher("Matematika 1#1#0@Fizika 1#1#6@Osnovi na injenernoto proektirane 1#1#5@PIK 1#1#6@Matematika 2#2#6@Fizika 2#2#6@Osnovi na injenernoto proektirane 2#2#4@");
    Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher("Matematika 1#1#0@Fizika 1#1#6@Osnovi na injenernoto proektirane 1#1#5@PIK 1#1#6@Matematika 2#2#6@Fizika 2#2#6@Osnovi na injenernoto proektirane 2#2#4@");


    while(matcher1.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher1.group(1));
        while (matcher2.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher2.group(1) + "\t");
            System.out.println(matcher2.group(1) + "\t");
            System.out.println(matcher2.group(1) + "\t");
        }

    }
```

but it didn't work out. "pattern2" works fine but only if the source string is: "Matematika 1#1#0@".... That led to the idea of two matchers. One for dividing the string into small strings, and the second to get the info.

I'll be glad to hear any kind of ideas, about how can I make it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is String.split an option?

Comment: Rather not. I have to save data from the string in two dimensional array and I don't think it wouldn't be really practical to create arrays with split and than putting them in to my array.

Comment: What exactly do you want to get from this string?

Comment: It is something like:

"subject#semester#grade@subject#semester#grade@.... and so on.

I need an array[number of records][3] where i have info about:
subject | semester | grade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way, using look-behind and look-ahead assertions to locate your groups of subject and numbers and then use matching groups to extract individual parts for each match:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=[^@])(.+?)#(\\d)#(\\d)(?=@)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Matematika 1#1#0@Fizika 1#1#6@Osnovi na injenernoto proektirane 1#1#5@PIK 1#1#6@Matematika 2#2#6@Fizika 2#2#6@Osnovi na injenernoto proektirane 2#2#4@");
while(m.find())
{
    if (m.groupCount() == 3) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
        System.out.println(m.group(3));
   }
}
```